# What happens when multiple packages registered to same broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Consider a broadcast receiver as part of a library (com.example.abc.MyBroadcastReceiver) responsible for handling `com.example.action.CUSTOMACTION_A` and it's bundled with two applications say (com.example.app1, com.example.app2). Consider `app1` registering this broadcast receiver implicitly within it's application class file. The other one `app2` registers this broadcast receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`. So people who would like to call the receiver in `app2` has to invoke with package name (Oreo+).

**Application2 (app2)**

```
<rreceiver android:name="com.example.abc.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.action.CUSTOMACTION_A" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Application1 (app1)**

MyApplication.java

```
import com.example.abc.MyBroadcastReceiver;

    public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.example.action.CUSTOMACTION_A");
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to invoke this broadcast from adb shell like,

> adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.action.CUSTOMACTION_A

I'm expecting `app1` to receive this broadcast since this is registered within code for the same action. But now both `app1` and `app2` is not receiving this broadcast. I'm puzzled with what's going on here.

When I remove `app2` - `app1` is able to receive the broadcast.

Comment: Implicit broadcasts are banned on Android 8.0+.

Comment: I agree with you @CommonsWare. Implicit broadcasts are banned from declaring them in AndroidManifest but we can register for an action in code so it can be alive as long as the application is alive. Here is a good reference :  (https://www.journaldev.com/23653/android-oreo-implicit-and-explicit-broadcast-receiver) "How to handle Implicit Receivers in Android Oreo?"

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Makes sense. Edited the question.

Comment: Are you certain that `app1` is running at the time of the broadcast? Have you confirmed that its `Application` class is actually running? Have you listed it as the `android:name` on the `<application>` element in your manifest? How are you determining whether the Receiver's `onReceive()` executes?

Comment: I'm very sure both apps were running (confirmed with adb shell ps) at that time @MikeM. I've registered my application class in AndroidManifest too.

Comment: Removing `app1` is making `app2` receiving the broadcast. I'm puzzled why.

Comment: What exactly does `MyBroadcastReceiver` do, and how are you determining that it's doing it? Also, which version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: I'm on Android-Pie.

Comment: You have "Consider app1 registering this broadcast receiver implicitly within it's application class file. The other one app2 registers this broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest.xml.", but your code seems to be opposite of that. And, I'll echo Mike's question: how are you determining what is and is not working? What is the receiver doing?

Comment: @CommonsWare : Sorry for this miss. I've edited the question. "how are you determining what is and is not working" - I just have a log print at the very beginning of `onReceive` which I'm not receiving - based on which I'm saying that I'm not receiving the broadcast.

Comment: Check to see if you are getting any system messages in Logcat at the time that you execute your `adb` command to send the broadcast. They may give you some clues.